# ¿Cómo seleccionar únicamente registros dese x a y?

Tags: sql, sql-server

En `mysql`, la siguiente consulta me permite mostrar los registros de una posición a otra que deseemos:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 15, 10
```

¿Cómo haría esta consulta en **Sql Server** ?

Comment: Segun recuerdo una ves hice algo asi pero se hace usando el Top y poniendo condiciones, solo que es un poco fastidioso, lo que puedes hacer es en tu front end intentar filtrarlo desde ahi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En SQL server dispones del [`TOP <n>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para indicar la cantidad máxima de filas que deseas mostrar, sin embargo, no hay una forma tan concisa  para establecer desde que fila deseas mostrar. Para lograr esto, una posiblidad de "numerar las filas" mediante [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) y usar este dato calculado como filtro, para lo cual necesitas usar una subconsulta.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT  TOP 10 T.*
    FROM (SELECT *,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
                 FROM Orders 
    ) T
    WHERE T.RN >= 15
```

O incluso:

```
SELECT  T.*
    FROM (SELECT *,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
                 FROM Orders 
    ) T
    WHERE T.RN BETWEEN 15 and 25
```

**Importante**:  [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) te permite establecer el orden de numeración, como no conozco las columnas de tu tabla uso `(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))`, pero para ser correcto, deberías establecer aquí el orden que quieres tal como cualquier clausula de orden, por ejemplo: `(ORDER BY col1 desc, col 2 asc)`. Válido a partir de la versión 2008.

Otra posibilidad, que honestamente no conocía, y que está disponible a partir de SQL Server 2012 es usar las clausulas [`OFFSET FETCH`](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx)

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Orders 
    ORDER BY OrderId
        OFFSET 14 ROWS            -- Filas a descartar
        FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;  -- Filas a mostrar
```

Estas clausulas solo pueden usarse con el `ORDER` por lo que es necesario indicarlo, en el ejemplo anterior, asumo que existe una columnas `OrderId`.

Comment: gracias, la ultima sintaxis me a funcionado muy bien,saludos